# How to install digikam5 on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, dependencies, ppa, digikam

After adding the [`ppa:philip5/extra` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~philip5/+archive/ubuntu/extra?field.series_filter=xenial)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip5/extra
apt update ; apt upgrade
```

I  attempted to install `digikam5` package and got the error:

```
$ apt install  digikam5
…
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 digikam5 : Depends: libmarblewidget-qt5-23 (>= 4:15.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Update**

```
$ apt install digikam5 libmarblewidget-qt5-23
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmarblewidget-qt5-23 : Depends: libastro1 (= 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu2) but 4:16.04.3-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04~ppa63 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So an lower version of `libastro1` is required than the one going to be installed.

#### Question

How do I install the version 5 of digikam?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the exact version (`libastro1=4:15.12.3-0ubuntu2`) allows to install:

```
apt install \
    digikam5 \
    libmarblewidget-qt5-23 \
    libastro1=4:15.12.3-0ubuntu2
```